# Grant Android 6.0+ permissions for automatic testing with Robotium

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, robotium

I am testing an app with Robotium and apparently it is not possible to access the popups and click on "Allow" to grant a permission when the app requests it, because these popups belong to the system and are therefore not accessible by robotium.

I know that I can grant all permissions when starting my tests via the command line with `$adb shell pm install -g com.my.tests` but I need to do this in my code, ideally directly in my test class at the beginning of the test. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If it is even possible - it is probably an interactive action - with some kind of popups, that user must accept. In other case it means that any app can silently grant permissions to itself or other apps. I guess that non-interactive command line granting if more appropriate for automated testing.

Comment: @Serhio I'm sure that it's normally not possible. For apps that will be released in the Play Store it's mandatory to request the permissions. But I thought that maybe it's possible for the debug versions.